# Django upgrade to 4.2 admin static files issue

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I am currently using django 3.2 and would like to upgrade to 4.2 soon. Doing so on a local environment and using `python manage.py collectstatic` works. However the problem comes when I try to deploy this to a development environment.

The new admin static files are not loading which causes the django admin page to look dysfunctional. Particularly, django 4.2 introduces a `dark_theme.css` static file which returns a 404 error when looking at the browser network tab. On my local environment, the file returns a 200 ok.

This is the most similar [thread](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/help-django-4-2-admin-page-css-issue/20196/41) to my issue I could find on the official django forum, however there is not a clear fix for the problem (perhaps because there are a lot of reasons why the issue could be happening)

I am using nginx for the server. We have a CI process that runs `collectstatic` then copies the output to a docker container and I have this nginx configuration to get the static files:

```
 location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/;
 }
```

In django settings, I have this configuration:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "ui/build/static"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Such that the static files are generated at `STATIC_ROOT` then the docker container copies them to `/usr/share/nginx/html/` correctly.

I have tried the same process but with a `--clear` flag for the `collectstatic` command, but no luck. I have also tried upgrading to django 4.2.0 explicitly as some people reported this version works, but again no luck. And of course I tried refreshing my browser cache.

Not sure what else it could be, it looks like the static files are there (particularly `dark_theme.css` seems to exist in the right place) but when fetching the files from the browser I get the 404.

Any thoughts or other things I can try/check would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well `STATIC_ROOT` should be `STATIC_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/html/static/'`

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem `collectstatic` runs first, then the static files are copied to `/usr/share/nginx/html/static/` and checking this location in the development environment shows the static files correctly in there.

Comment: I've seen some Compose setups that use a named volume to publish static files from the application container to the Nginx proxy, but this actually works by making an extra copy of the static files, and the old files in the volume will hide any changes in the image.  Do you have a setup like this, with Compose `volumes:` mounted over the application's `.../static` directory?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not using docker-compose for deployment for this project, so it should not be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a common problem that can be due to a lot of reasons, here's what my issue was:

Previously this is how the docker container was built:

```
poetry run python manage.py collectstatic
npm install
npm run build
docker build ...
```

The problem was the the npm build was overwriting the static files as they were both in a `/build/static` route, solution for this was to reverse the two. Just with this, the issue was still there, also needed to add `--clear` to `collectstatic`.

```
npm install
npm run build
poetry run python manage.py collectstatic --clear
docker build ...
```